# DOMPDF issue with margin on div

Tags: dompdf

I have issue with margin on dompdf using plain html. I have added margin-top to div but adds some extra space at the the end of element.

It works perfectly if no margin-top is added. As shown in following screenshot
[image]

As I add margin-top to div it adds extra spacing at the end of that div as shown in following screenshots. HTML is perfect but issue in generated pdf only.
HTML 1:
[image]
PDF 1:
[image]

HTML 2:
[image]
PDF 2: 
[image]

I searched a lot for the issue but cannot find any solution regarding this why it adds space after the element when I use `margin-top:15px;` I tried `margin: 15px 0 0 0;` but no luck with that too.

- I am using latest version of dompdf
  HTML Code snippest:

```css
    *{margin:0; padding:0}
    body { padding: 50px 0; margin: 0px; font-family: Georgia; }
    ul{padding-left:40px; }
    .resume-container {width: 90%;margin:0 auto;background-color: #fff;}
    .reasume-header{width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #DADADA}
    .reasume-header .head{font-weight: bold;font-size: 28px;}
    .small-font {font-size: 12px;}

    .header{margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:0;}
    h1{font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0px;}
    .content{margin-top: 15px}
    #template1 .header .title-header h1{background: #769AC2; color: #FFF; padding: 5px 0; text-align:center}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"><title>Resume</title><style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="resume-container" id="template1">

        <div class="header w100 temp6-hidden" border="0" id="expertise_part" style="clear:both;">
            <div class="w100 align-top title-header">
                <h1>EXPERTISE</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="inner-content" style="clear:both;">
                <div class="content details" style="background: #F0F0F0">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Wide range of design experience building mobile sites to E-Commerce front end sites.</li>
                        <li>Expert in Joomla and WordPress Customization.</li>
                        <li>Highly proficient in Photoshop, Illustrator, HTML5 and XSLT.</li>
                        <li>Experienced with social media marketing and search engine optimization.</li>
                        <li>Highly skilled in layout designs for print in InDesign and custom logotypes.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="content details">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ac massa a felis molestie blandit sed a ex. Nullam rutrum mi et ultricies pellentesque. Proin ullamcorper, nunc eget mattis pellentesque, sem urna sagittis lacus, vitae scelerisque metus mauris eu magna. Integer commodo, ipsum ac ullamcorper aliquet, mauris massa imperdiet lorem, eget consectetur turpis quam sed neque. Nulla condimentum sem tortor, non imperdiet nunc fermentum nec. Donec lacus risus, dictum nec sem at, dapibus sagittis lectus. Duis tincidunt elit eu dui placerat pretium. Aliquam elementum urna ex, vel facilisis nunc dictum sit amet.Duis volutpat tincidunt laoreet. Nullam congue, metus vitae dapibus varius, ipsum turpis sollicitudin sapien, ut faucibus tellus erat id magna. Nunc consectetur dolor vel molestie lobortis. Proin volutpat commodo metus, non luctus turpis pulvinar et. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam consequat imperdiet ligula. Quisque finibus, nibh sit amet posuere maximus, diam dolor volutpat lacus, ut luctus enim dolor sed urna. Donec nec enim ut risus cursus tincidunt ut et libero.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header w100 temp6-hidden" border="0" id="education_part">
            <div class="w100 align-top title-header">
                <h1>EDUCATION</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="inner-content">
                <div class="w100 content " style="background: #F0F0F0">
                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="lft" style="width:60%">
                                <strong class="dt_area">ABC University</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" style="width:40%;"><strong class="dt_area">INDIA, Kerala</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="lft" style="width:60%"><strong class="dt_area">MCA</strong></td>
                            <td align="right" style="width:40%;"><strong class="dt_area"><strong class="dt_area">2/2001 - 3/2004</strong></strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="content details" style="width:100%;clear:both;font-size: 14px; font-family:Arial;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ac massa a felis molestie blandit sed a ex. Nullam rutrum mi et ultricies pellentesque.<br />
                    Proin ullamcorper, nunc eget mattis pellentesque, sem urna sagittis lacus, vitae scelerisque metus mauris eu magna. Integer commodo, ipsum ac ullamcorper aliquet, mauris massa imperdiet lorem, eget consectetur turpis quam sed neque.<br />
                    Nulla condimentum sem tortor, non imperdiet nunc fermentum nec. Donec lacus risus, dictum nec sem at, dapibus sagittis lectus. Duis tincidunt elit eu dui placerat pretium. Aliquam elementum urna ex, vel facilisis nunc dictum sit amet.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code snippet also shows that spacing. Be sure to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Doesn't show any. Look for the highlighted area with background in pdf and html. 15px margin-top set on content but it shows extra spacing at the end of that div in almost all sections. Please go through 1st image and then html/pdf screenshot that I have added

Comment: Sorry, I mistook where the extra space was showing up. But my comment still holds...I'm not seeing that extra space (in the grayish box). Have you attempted to render the above snippet? Perhaps some styling is missing?

Comment: I have supplied only html to generate pdf. HTML works fine. issues is in generated PDF only. Try to generate pdf using above code snippets in DOMPDF

Comment: I understand, but when I render the above sample I'm [not seeing the issue](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php?identifier=716fc810fb4945ed7e357d842ed254c9) you indicated. I _am_ seeing a separate issue related to the positioning of the list bullets, but I think that's a result of some of the styling. Have you attempted to render the sample you provided?